# accessing data from oracle database

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

machine A has table1 (database in oracle version- 11g)
machine B has table2 (database in oracle version- 11g)

I have created a database link in machine A to access data from machine B

So when I use the select query in machine A `select * from table2@dblink` I can access the data.

The problem is, I want to create link but I don't want to specify the **link name** like in above query.

Is there a way to access data remotely without specifying a link name. The reason behind doing this is to have access over data from remote machine but the users should not know where the data is coming from.

Comment: Oracle Synonyms might help. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7001.htm

Answer (score 1):

You could create a view to access `TABLE2@DBLINK` in the database on machine A:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW TABLE2 AS
  SELECT * FROM TABLE2@DBLINK
```

Now on machine A you can write

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE2
```

without specifying the link.

Best of luck.

Comment: A synonym would be another alternative

Comment: so like this i have to create link for every query whether it is select or insert or delete or update

Comment: No, you define *one* view (or synonym) for each remote table.